# Скрипт загрузки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужен скрипт, который будет с браузера загружать в определённую папку файлы по типу phpuploader. Обязательный формат загрузки должен быть PNG и не должен превышать 5кб.
Так же должен быть выбор между двумя местами загрузки. Например, если галочку поставить на против надписи Skins, то он будет загружать файлы на сервер в папку Skins. А если галочку поставить напротив Cloak, то соответственно в Cloak и будет загружать!

Answer (score 1):

**Файл upload.html**

```
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <head>
    <title>Загрузка файлов на сервер</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <h2><p><b> Форма для загрузки файлов </b></p></h2>
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="filename"><br>
          Skins<input type="radio" name="check" value="Skins" checked="checked"><br>
          Cloak<input type="radio" name="check" value="Cloak"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
          </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Файл upload.php**

```
<?php
        $ext = preg_replace('/(?:.*)(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]{3,4})$/','$1', $_FILES['filename']['name']);
        if ($ext !== ".png"){echo "Загружаемый файл не .png ";
        exit;   
        };
       if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*5)
       {
         echo ("Размер файла превышает пять килобайт<br>");
         exit;
       }
       // Проверяем загружен ли файл
       if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
       {
         // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
         // из временной директории в конечную
        if ($_POST['check']=="Skins"){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "Skins/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
                };
        if ($_POST['check']=="Cloak"){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "Cloak/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
                };
         echo "Файл загружен";
       } else {
          echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
       }
    ?>
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Вот: [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Писать за вас никто не будет!